# asp.net edit text and save it to database

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, html, asp.net

So I got text in a div box on my Page.
I now want to make it editable and save the changes with a button click.

I already know how to make the text in the div box editable but how do i save the changes to the database?
And where do I put it?

```
$("#Bearbeiten").click(function() {
        $("#Beschreibung").attr("contenteditable", "true");)}
```

To get my data i use ajax and i already tried to get the data and post it back to the database but either I did something wrong or just not the right way to post back the data.

```
var VersionID = $(this).data("versionid");
        $.ajax({
            dataType: "json",
            url: "api/Beschreibung/getText?xVersionID=" + VersionID,
            type: "get"
```

I hope someone can help me.

Summarized: How do I get the data and how do i change it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should:

1. create a `form`;
2. POST the data to the webserver (you can use jQuery for that, but I would suggest a simple `form` with a submit button;
3. Handle the POST data on the server. It seems you are using MVC. There are tutorials for that [all over the internet](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/639709/Getting-Data-From-View-to-Controller-in-MVC);
4. Get the posted data and send it to your database. You can use Entity Framework for that, or ADO.NET.